# Minimum Value from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I can't figure this out, I've tried different ways but have been unsuccessful.

My database consists of empid and checkin

I want to find the lowest checkin value which is a number and get the empid for that.

> select empid, MIN(checkin) FROM emp GROUP BY empid LIMIT 1

Is what I was doing.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select empid, MIN(checkin) FROM emp GROUP BY empid ORDER BY MIN(checkin) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select empid, checkin from emp order by checkin ASC LIMIT 1
```